# How do I use Python to easily expand variables to strings?

Tags: python, string, variables, idioms, expand

What's a nice idiom to do this:

Instead of:
`print "%s is a %s %s that %s" % (name, adjective, noun, verb)`

I want to be able to do something to the effect of:
`print "{name} is a {adjective} {noun} that {verb}"`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
"{name} is a {adjective} {noun} that {verb}".format(**locals())
```

- `locals()` gives a reference to the current namespace (as a dictionary).
- `**locals()` unpacks that dictionary into keyword arguments (`f(**{'a': 0, 'b': 1})` is `f(a=0, b=1)`).
- `.format()` is ["the new string formatting"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), which can by the way do a lot more (e.g. `{0.name}` for the name attribute of the first positional argument).

Alternatively, [`string.template`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) (again, with locals if you want to avoid a redundant `{'name': name, ...}` dict literal).

Comment: For more details and options: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: @Harem: +1 I was actually looking for that link, but found the PEP first... must be some flaw in my search algorithm.

Comment: Passing locals() to a function is usually a very bad idea.  It leads to parameter creep, where it's impossible to tell which variables are actually intended to be passed along and which are actually locals.

Comment: @Glenn: Generally, I would agree ("that function only needs x and y, why should I pass it a, b, c and d too?"). But in this particular case (putting a few locals into a template string), I consider it the best solution (and others seems to agree) in that it avoids redundancy and leaves the template string self-documenting.

Comment: Having an explicit list of variables to include isn't redundant; omitting that list quickly leads to sloppy code as soon as the calling function is nontrivial--it's something you'll come to regret later.  It's simple enough to write a function to create a dict from the keys of another dict, so you can say eg. `make_dict(locals(), ["key1", "key2", "key3"])`.

Comment: @Glenn: `"{adjective} {noun}".format(adjective=adjective, noun=noun)` *is* redundant. The helper you propose is only slightly better. And again, I totally do not endorse this for anything except filling out template strings.

Answer (score 11):

Since Python 3.6 you can now use this syntax, called f-strings, which is very similar to your suggestion 9 years ago

```py
print(f"{name} is a {adjective} {noun} that {verb}")
```

f-strings or formatted string literals will use variables from the scope they're used in, or other valid Python expressions.

```py
print(f"1 + 1 = {1 + 1}")  # prints "1 + 1 = 2"
```

- Here's a link to the documentation of Formatted string literals: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings
- And here's a link to the PEP that formalizes the feature: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 6):

use [`string.Template`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings)

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> t = Template("$name is a $adjective $noun that $verb")
>>> t.substitute(name="Lionel", adjective="awesome", noun="dude", verb="snores")
'Lionel is a awesome dude that snores'
```

Comment: Awesome.  Flattery gets you *everywhere*

Answer (score 3):

For python 2 do:

```
print name,'is a',adjective,noun,'that',verb
```

For python 3 add parens:

```
print(name,'is a',adjective,noun,'that',verb)
```

If you need to save it to a string, you'll have to concatenate with the `+` operator and you'll have to insert spaces.  `print` inserts a space at all the `,` unless there is a trailing comma at the end of the parameters, in which case it forgoes the newline.

To save to string var:

```
result = name+' is a '+adjective+' '+noun+' that '+verb
```

Comment: Note that in Pyhon 2, this prints a tuple instead of some strings ;) (just drop the parens)

Answer (score -1):

Since python 3.8 it's also possible to expand variable names into strings which can be very useful for logging and debugging:

```py
name="John Doe"
print(f"Found person {name=}")
# will print:
"Found person name='John Doe'"

# vs no variable name
print(f"Found person {name=}")
# will print:
"Found person John Doe"
```

Note the `=` sign after variable which tells the formatter to include  variable name.