# Variable expansion in Python regex

Tags: python, regex, formatting, variable-expansion

I am trying to write a script in Python which "cleans" a number of file-fed text like this:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    number = 1
    cleanText = re.sub('number.','',line).strip() 
    number = number + 1
    print cleanText
```

An example file would be: 1. Hello, World 2. Hello earth

What I need to do here is remove the numbering and the dots along with leading blank spaces in one fell swoop. But how on earth can I first perform a simple variable expansion?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Why are you assigning 1 to `number` and then incrementing it by 1 each iteration? (also why is `number` there at all, it's never used)

Comment: Couldn't you just use a regular expression that matches any number?

Comment: I think you looking for the PHP feature where a variable referenced in a string can be replace with it's value on echo.  Python does not have this.  There is `printf` (which is slightly different), but wouldn't apply here anyways

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I could simply do it with a regular expression. However in this case I wish to follow the substitution path which btw also works in a number of cases where regexes don't. Jason I don't know. I thought number would somehow be replaced by the value of 1.

Comment: There is this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/4840617/16959 which looks like variable expansion, but you are actually passing arguments to a `format` method that is parsing a string and substituting values as it finds them

Comment: I 've red about locals() in the past but haven't quite figured out how to properly use it. Maybe an example..?

Comment: @JasonSperske this is about the worst thing one could do to solve this incredibly simple problem.

Comment: @l4mpi, I agree, I'm just trying to provide some continuity if Konos5 has an idea of how Strings worked in Python based on other programming languages

Comment: @JasonSperske To be honest I am just learning the basics and coming from a bash environment it came to me as a surprise how hard it can be to perform a plain replacement. Anyway thanks for your time. I think I get the picture now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others said, you should simply use a regular expression that matches any number, such as `r"\d"` or `r"\d+"`. However, for learning purposes, here is the answer to what you did ask.

The closest useful equivalent of "variable expansion" is the string formatting operator:

```
cleanText = re.sub('%d.' % number, line).strip()
```

You could also use `str(number) + '.'` to achieve the same effect. There are several more problems with your code:

- your loop is wrong; if you're iterating over `range(1, 10)`, then you don't need to increment `number` manually.
- you probably meant `range(1, 11)`.
- `.` in regular expression syntax matches any characters; you want `\.`.

A cleaned-up version might look like this:

```
cleanText = line.strip()
for i in xrange(1, 11):
    cleanText = re.sub(r'%d\.', '' , cleanText)
```

Comment: In the third line, what's the r used for before '% ?

Comment: @Konos5 It's a so-called raw string, meaning backslashes are treated as literals and are not used for escape sequences (except for escaping the enclosing quote type). See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: @Konos5 The **r** in front of ``%d\.`` is completely unjustified. Such an **r** deactivates the influence of the backslash present in some escaped sequences OF A STRING, such as ``\n \t \a \b \\ etc``. The sequence ``\.`` is not an escaped sequence at the level of string: ``.`` is a dot and ``\.`` is a backslash and a dot. Point. ``\.`` is an escaped sequence at the level of a regex's pattern. It is more easy to use raw strings (**r** in front of) when they represent a regex's pattern intended to represent a backslash in it. Apart this case , it brings nothing to use raw strings

Comment: The idea is that you don't have to *think* about which characters following the backslash are escape sequences. Some escape sequences are obscure or rarely used (`\a`, `\b`, `\v`), some subtly differ between languages (Emacs and GCC grok `\e`, Python doesn't), and some are interpreted differently (shells interpret `\.` as `.`, Python as `\.`). In a raw string, you just type \ knowing that it won't be interpreted as anything except the literal \ character. This is why it is a good idea to use raw strings for all regexes.

Answer (score 3):

If your file format is guaranteed to be like you said:

```
1. Hello, World
2. Hello earth
```

You don't even need to use a regex, you could just use `split` and `join`:

```
clean_line = ' '.join(line.split(' ')[1:]).lstrip()

>>> ' '.join("1. Hello, world".split(' ')[1:])
'Hello, world'
```

Or, if you still wanted to do substitution, this `replace`-based code may work:

```
number = 1
for line in file_handle:
  clean_line = line.replace("%d. " % number, "").lstrip()
  number += 1
```

Comment: or, `for number, line in enumerate(file_handle, 1): ...`

Comment: @Valdogg21 Your second solution with ``replace())`` is unpythonically dumb. Your first solution is based on a good idea, but read the doc on ``strip()`` and write: ``line.lstrip().split(None,1)[1]`` for a line, and ``print '\n'.join(line.lstrip().split(None,1)[1] for line in text.splitlines(1))`` for a text

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
fp = open('line','r')
for line in fp:
    pattern = re.match(r'[0-9]*\.(.*)',line)
    if pattern:
        print pattern.group(1)
    else:
        print line
```